# Solve the congruence $6x+15y \equiv 9 \pmod {18}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Solve the congruence $6x+15y \equiv 9\pmod {18}$

Approach:

$(6,18)=6$, so $$15y \equiv 9\pmod 6$$
$$15y \equiv 3\pmod 6$$

So the equation will have $(15,6)$ solutions. Now we divide by 3

$$5y \equiv 1\pmod 2$$.

Solving the Diophantine equation we get $y \equiv1\pmod 2 $, so $y=1+2m$

$$6x \equiv 9-15y\pmod {18}$$
$$6x \equiv 9-15(1+2m)\pmod {18}$$
$$6x \equiv -6-30m\pmod {18}$$

Divide by 6

$$x \equiv -1-5m\pmod 3$$

The right solution is $x-m \equiv 2\pmod 3$. I have $x+5m \equiv 2\pmod 3$
$$x-m+6m \equiv 2\pmod 3$$ $$x-m \equiv 2\pmod 3$$

Wolfram alpha says $y=1+2t$ and $x=t+3d+2$

Answer (score 2):

Dividing everything by $3$, including the modulus, we get the equivalent congruence
$$2x+5y\equiv 3\pmod{6}.$$
It is convenient to rewrite this as $2x-y\equiv 3\pmod{6}$, or equivalently $y\equiv 2x-3\equiv 2x+3\pmod{6}$.

Now we have a parametric solution: $x\equiv t\pmod{6}$, $y\equiv 2t+3\pmod{6}$. To write it out at length, set $t=0,1,2,3,4,5$. The first two solutions are then $x\equiv 0\pmod{6}$, $y\equiv 3\pmod{6}$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod{6}$, $y\equiv 5\pmod{6}$. Four more to go.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my answer is okay.
$6x+15y \equiv 9(mod 18)$

$=> 2x+5y \equiv 3(mod 6)$

$=> 2x-y \equiv 3(mod 6)$

i.e $2x-y-3 \equiv 0(mod 2)$ and $\equiv 0(mod 3)$

this means $y+1 \equiv 0(mod 2)$ and $x+y \equiv 0(mod 3)$

Write $y=2p+1$ and so $x-p +1 \equiv 0(mod 3)$

Then use parametric equations.

Comment: why is $2x-y\equiv3(mod6)$

Comment: write $5y \equiv 6y-y$

Comment: you get $2x-y\equiv 0(mod 3)$. How do you get $x+y\equiv 0(mod 3)$. Is it because $-x-y\equiv 0(mod 3)$ implies $x+y\equiv 0(mod 3$)?

Comment: $2x-y-3 \equiv 0(mod3)$ implies $3x-x-y-3 \equiv 0(mod3)$ i.e $-x-y \equiv 0(mod3)$ i.e $x+y \equiv 0(mod3)$

Comment: can you provide another exercise?. My book just has that one?

Comment: You might find sufficient exercises in this book :http://www.hexagon.edu.vn/images/resources/upload/dec3c0b23f6d5bffa9c661616b1658fd/Titu_Andreescu_Dorin_Andrica_Ion_Cucurezeanu_an_introduction_to_diophantine_equations_1377960528.pdf

Comment: based on wolfram alpha, your solution is wrong. You got x=3t+p+1 and it should be x=3t+p+2

Comment: Can u find logical flaw in my solution? I don't see any. idk

Comment: u can use $2x-y \equiv 3(mod6)$ itself.

Comment: how would that yield to the right solution?

Comment: By parametrizing the equation in $x \equiv t(mod6)$ and $y \equiv 2t-3(mod6)$. That would be easiest.

Comment: My solution follows as well right?

Comment: I was confused about the last step $x\equiv 1-5m(mod 3)$. I thought that there is just one solution to that equation hence gcd(1,3)=1, but trying different m's generate different solutions for x. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Sorry why one solution?

Comment: you have to look for all forms of x i.e x=3k, 3k+1, 3k+2

Comment: $1*x \equiv 1-5m(mod3)$, so the equation is solvable if the $gcd(1,3)|1-5m$ It does and it's 1 so the equations has just one solution.

Comment: But x is a variable. No, you can't write that way I'm afraid.

Comment: It's a general way to make it sqeezed in a parametric form when you have two variables in a equation.

Comment: Look at my solution on the post.

Comment: in your solution $y\neq 2p+1$, that's the problem

Comment: ?? you agree that $2x-y-3 \equiv 0(mod2)$ there right? but $2x \equiv 0(mod2)$ so I can write $-y-3 \equiv 0(mod2)$ which means $y=2p+1$ for some $p$

Comment: my point there was to break the $(mod6)$ in two parts. u might/might not do it.

Comment: $y+1\equiv 0(mod 2)$. How did you get $y=2p+1$ if your equation shows $y=2p-1$?

Comment: y is a odd number that's it. u can write it anything.

Comment: ohhh yess xd, so I don't know what went wrong in your solution. It looks very good to me.

Comment: $1 \equiv -1 (mod2)$

Comment: I learned a lot in this conversation. You have to squeeze the numbers so they are drained in the mod n. I didn't see it that way.

Comment: Lol , nothing went wrong in my solution. I'm lazy to check. U r probably not checking correct.

Comment: OHHhh yes you are right. The solution is right hahaha.

Answer (score -2):

Wolfram answer:
$y = 2c + 1$
$x = c + 3d + 2$

Comment: so the y is right. What's wrong with the x?. I got 3d+2